# ¿Cómo configurar .htaccess para un subdominio?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirección, reescritura-url, mod-rewrite

Estoy utilizando [este proyecto de código abierto](https://github.com/GeekyTheory/Automatic-API-REST) que trata sobre cómo hacer una API REST.

En mi servidor local cree un host virtual para hacer un subdominio del tipo `api.dominio.dev`, y en el proyecto dice que hay que configurar el `.htaccess` para que no haya errores de 404 en la página.

Pero en el ejemplo que ellos colocan para la regla, resulta que el proyecto lo hacen para acceder de la siguiente forma: `localhost/proyecto` y la regla del .htaccess es sencilla

```
RewriteRule ^api/ Automatic-API-REST/api.php
```

pero para hacerlo sobre un subdominio, ¿cómo deberia de ser?

Comment: No comprendo bien tu pregunta. La regla, conceptualmente, puede aplicarse tanto a una configuración de dominio único como a dominios virtuales. ¿qué problema te está dando?

Comment: Hola @jachguate el problema es este Not Found

The requested URL /api/get/City/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Tenes el .htaccess en la ruta principal del virtualhost? tu configuración de apache tiene activado el mod_rewrite?

Comment: Hola el htaccess esta entro de la carpeta de proyecto, y si el mod_rewrite esta activado en el apache

Comment: si el .htaccess está en su lugar y el mod_rewrite también, no debiera ocurrir el 404, a menos que no existiera Automatic-API-REST/api.php.  Algo huele mal... veamos ¿Qué te dice el log de acceso? ¿hay algo relevante en el log de errores? ¿Qué pasa si escribes la URL de un recurso que si existe en el sub-dominio?, ¿lo sirve correctamente?. Si es así, podrías escribir una regla rewrite para ese mismo recurso y ver si la aplica correctamente.

Answer (score 4):

Si lo he entendido bien. En el caso del tutorial, la URL de la API sería por ejemplo:

```
www.dominio.com/api/
```

Mientras que en tu caso sería:

```
api.dominio.com
```

Entonces, la regla `RewriteRule ^api/ Automatic-API-REST/api.php` no vale porque hace referencia a una URL que va al directorio "api". Lo que necesitas es una regla que compruebe que el subdominio es "api" y entonces redirija a un directorio o a un fichero en concreto.

Basándome en [esta respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740851/3695983), podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.dominio\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com/Automatic-API-REST/api.php$1 [L]
```

Que viene a ser:

- Activa el motor de reescritura de URLs (línea 1),
- Si el host es del tipo "api.dominio.com" (línea 2),
- Entonces redirige al fichero api.php dentro del directorio Automatic-API-REST manteniendo la petición (línea 3).

De este modo, una URL como: `api.dominio.com/get/City` sería reescrita como `www.dominio.com/api.php/get/City`.

Comment: Hola gracias por aclarar mi situación, veo que esa regla es para reescribir la url con www.dominio.com/api.php.get/City, pero yo quiero que se conserve con el subdominio, de  www.api.dominio.com, otra cosa que noto en las urls que genera el proyecto esque despues del dominio apunta como si fuera un controlador o una carpeta api de la siguiente forma www.api.dominio.com/api/get/City y de la forma como tu lo planteas es con el archivo api.php/get/city , el archivo .htaccess lo tengo entro de la carpeta del proyecto, lo dejo hay o saco que quede entro del dir www/ de mi servidor, saludos